# Xamarin.Forms MSAL authentication java.exe exited with code 1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

```
<activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- example -->
                <!-- <data android:scheme="msalaaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee" android:host="auth" /> -->
                <data android:scheme="msal37a0fb96-9bf2-4c63-a5e0-942ade68b351" android:host="auth" />
            
            </intent-filter>            
        </activity>
```

While trying to run my Xamarin.Forms application on an Android device, I am getting a "Java.exe exited with code 1" error. I have been trying to implement authentication using Azure AD B2C and I have to add the above quoted code to the Android Manifest.

Quite unfortunately, I know that it is the one causing the compilation error because when I remove it, the app compiles but of course, doesn't work properly in the end.

How do I fix this?

**Edit 1**

```
"C:\Users\user\source\repos\XamPaper\XamPaper.Android\XamPaper.Android.csproj" (Build;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
1>(_ManifestMerger target) -> 
1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1482,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I have tried to comb through the build logs and I suppose the error has something to do with my dependencies in the project file. I will post it here.

**Project Csproj File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{CA812816-3F4B-4055-A0F5-7D080BD3CAB7}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{c9e5eea5-ca05-42a1-839b-61506e0a37df}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>XamPaper.Droid</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>XamPaper.Android</AssemblyName>
    <Deterministic>True</Deterministic>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v12.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <MandroidI18n />
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client">
      <Version>4.42.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\icon_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\icon.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\launcher_foreground.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\XamPaper\XamPaper.csproj">
      <Project>{34B7A427-0AE6-40FB-BF15-196F95C5097C}</Project>
      <Name>XamPaper</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: When do you get that error? After it has been deployed to the device? Or while it is compiling?

Comment: While compiling.

Comment: Check the build log, there should be more information.

Comment: The log seems to think it's problem with my dependencies. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add `android:exported="true"` to your activity as per https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4737
The link is for Maui but is the same solution on Xamarin.

The project builds successfully and MSAL works correctly after adding android:exported="true" to the activity element in AndroidManifest.xml

Here is the Android Documentation about the Exported requirement in 31+.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

Comment: thank you very much good man I spent 3 days looking for the solution to that problem, I couldn't sleep anymore

Answer (score 2):

I did face the exact same problem just yesterday after setting up MSAL authentication for my Xamarin.Forms application. What solved the problem for me was changing the android:targetSdkVersion to 30 or lower. It was originally 31.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.xamarindemowithb2c">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="MSALSample.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />               
                <data android:scheme="msal<YourClientId>" android:host="auth"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>"
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

After changing it from 31 to 30 or lower, the solution would build and could be successfully deployed to the emulator and my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your code from the manifest and Try Replacing it with this class.
In your android project create a class name MsalActivity and add this;

```
    [Activity]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
         Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
         DataHost = "auth",
         DataScheme = "msal37a0fb96-9bf2-4c63-a5e0-942ade68b351")]
    public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
    {
    }
```