# Azure B2C broken when explicitly-declared value for android:exported is used

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

My Xamarin.Forms application uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. Currently, I have to use Android 12 instead of Android 10. According to the documentation, it required a certain change:

> Warning: If an activity, service, or broadcast receiver uses intent
> filters and doesn't have an explicitly-declared value for
> android:exported, your app can't be installed on a device that runs
> Android 12 or higher.

(https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#security)

This is my code from MsalActivity.cs:

```
namespace UserDetailsClient.Droid
{
  [Activity(Exported = false)]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataHost = "auth",
    DataScheme = "msal5c32fe58-4a77-49ea-8b5d-010c4a684e4f")]
  public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
  {
  }
}
```

After I added (Exported = false), I was able to deploy and run the app. But now I am not able to log in. The login screen does show up. And the user can enter the credentials, but after submitting, we get stuck on this screen:

[image]

Nothing new appears in the output window. How can this be diagnosed and fixed?

Comment: why your adding (Exported = false)

Comment: @AmjadS. Are you asking why I use "false", or why I added this parameter at all? I added it because that is what Android 12 requires, as it is stated in the document I quoted in my question. Without it, I could not even run the emulator. I used specifically "false", because the same document says, "If the app component includes the LAUNCHER category, set android:exported to true. In most other cases, set android:exported to false". Anyway, I tried true also, and it did not help.

Comment: if you replace it by [Activity] does it work? and did it worked on android less than 12?

Comment: @AmjadS. Yes, on Android 10 it had [Activity], and then it worked. But Android 12 requires android:exported. With just [Activity] it doesn't run: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1717347692.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #43): crc64b1e0d6e5becad47c.MsalActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to set the Exported = true. The official document says if the activity has any intent filter, the default value of it is true, so your project in Android 10, it's `Exported = true`. When you update to Android 12, you need to set it as true too.

You can check the official document:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I mentioned earlier, I tried true, and it did not help...

Comment: Sorry, my careless. Had you checked the logs when you get stuck on the screen?@DavidShochet

Comment: I tried it today on an emulator (Android 12.0 - API 31). It did not let me even enter the credentials, and this is the last output before it got stuck: The thread 0x10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
[libc] Requested dump for tid 5947 (aticrete.mobile) I am not sure if this is important, but the package name is actually com.laticrete.mobile.

Comment: I just tried to debug on a device, Android 10 (I don't have 12), and it worked. I don't know if the issue is the emulator or that Android 12. If the problem is the emulator's deficiency, then probably your answer fixes the issue... I will mark it so far.

Comment: Thanks for your mark and there is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305191/xamarin-forms-msal-authentication-java-exe-exited-with-code-1). It seems that the android version higher than 10 will meet the problem.@DavidShochet