# Error java.exe exited with code 1 Xamarin Firbase Messaging

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using nuget package `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` and `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`to receive push notifications in my app, previously it was working fine, but when I update `visual studio 2022 to 17.2.3` it stopped working

I Tried all of these:

- Update all nuget packages
- delete obj bin folder from all shared projects
- enable multidex
- install and include

`<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Guava" ExcludeAssets="all"> <Version>27.1.0</Version> </PackageReference>`

- https://techhelpnotes.com/c-working-through-package-reference-errors-with-firebase-and-a-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-error-xamarin/
- https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/379

and nothing i did before has worked

my code to receive push notifications:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Plugin.DeviceInfo;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        readonly AndroidNotificationManager _androidNotification = new AndroidNotificationManager();
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var mensajeData = message.Data;

            string title= mensajeData["notiTitle"];
            string bodymessage= mensajeData["notiBody"];

            _androidNotification.CreateLocalNotification(title, bodymessage);
        }

        public override void OnNewToken(string token)
        {
            base.OnNewToken(token);
            Preferences.Set("TokenFirebase", token);
        }
    }
}
```

if I remove `[Service]` or
`[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]` the code compiles correctly

Comment: Code 1 can happen for various reasons, try to set the build output verbosity to "Diagnostic" and check the build output again, the error should be more detailed. This setting is located at: Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run → MSBuild project build output verbosity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it was due to the update I made of visual studio because the android SDK was also updated, the solution was to edit `[Services]` to `[Services(Exported = true)]` for android +31, leaving the final code like this.

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    readonly AndroidNotificationManager _androidNotification = new AndroidNotificationManager();
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        var mensajeData = message.Data;

        string title= mensajeData["notiTitle"];
        string bodymessage= mensajeData["notiBody"];

        _androidNotification.CreateLocalNotification(title, bodymessage);
    }

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);
        Preferences.Set("TokenFirebase", token);
    }
}
```

After adding that, everything compiled correctly

font [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204864/11535892)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers here, I also had to export the broadcast reviver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
```